# An uncaught Exception was encountered - Type: RuntimeException in windows (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with my system when I opened localhost, it displays this error :

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: RuntimeException
>
> Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Project_model
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\txu\system\core\Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 344

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\txu\application\controllers\home.php
Line: 9
Function: model

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\txu\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

---

this model: Project_model.php

```
class Project_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

---

this is controller: Project.php

---

```
class Project extends CI_Controller{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('project_model');
}
```

this is my home controller: home.php

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{


function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Project_model');
}
```

---

before this it working, i dont know why it does not working right now. And the console show an error in localhost:
`GET http://localhost/txu/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Can anyone give me suggestion or idea? thank you.

Comment: sorry, this is code for Project_model.php.class Project_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

Comment: i already update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For project module;

Create the controller names as Project.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Project extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('project_model');

        echo $this->project_model->my_model_func();         
        echo "<br> This is the Project Controller";
    }
}
```

Create the model named as Project_Model.php

```
class Project_model extends CI_Model {

    public function my_model_func()
    {
        echo "Project_model model loaded with my_model_func";;
    }
}
```

And see the output on http://your-base-url/index.php/project
You should see the output as

```
Project_model model loaded with my_model_func
This is the Project Controller
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: `class Project_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }`

Comment: sorry, actually that was class for Project_model.

Comment: This may be because of name convention error, If you can replace this $this->load->model('project_model'); with $this->load->model('Project_model'); and also rename your controller home.php to Home.php.

Comment: Hey @Emma, I have updated the answer see if that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter around version 2.1; you instantiate model like below > Note that it starts on upper case

```
$this->load->model('Project_model');
```

While on codeigniter version 3+; you always instantiate model starting lower case, or should i say all lower case

```
$this->load->model('project_model');
```

Therefore I would like you to check on your codeigniter version if what fits you.

Same on Usage if you instantiate your model like "Project_model", then use it as:

```
$this->Project_model->action();
```

it has case sensitivity;